# QML animation takes too much CPU

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I made this simple snowfall animation in QML and it looks pretty good except I noticed it takes too much CPU. It constantly takes around ~9% of my Ubuntu laptop CPU and about ~34% on my imx8mm embedded device. Why is it taking so much CPU and how can I reduce CPU usage?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Window {
    id: root

    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: snowfallEmittorArea
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        color: "black"
        z:2

        ParticleSystem {
            id: particleSystem
        }

        Emitter {
            id: emitter
            anchors.fill: parent
            system: particleSystem
            emitRate: 10
            lifeSpan: 4000
            sizeVariation: 5
            lifeSpanVariation: 500
            velocity: AngleDirection {
                angle: 90
                angleVariation: 10
                magnitude: 100
                magnitudeVariation: 50
            }
        }

        ItemParticle {
            system: particleSystem
            delegate: Rectangle {
                height: 8
                width: 8
                radius: 5
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm open to exploring other less CPU-intensive ways to implementing this animation.

Comment: Have you tried other particle examples and gotten any better results?

Comment: @JarMan I tried the example in this book here (https://qmlbook.github.io/ch10-particles/particles.html) and it uses ~5% on my laptop so it's an improvement. I also noticed using ImageParticle instead of ItemParticle cut the usage by a third.

Comment: I don't have experience with the particle stuff, but maybe it's just slow. Will a video or animated gif work better?

Comment: @JarMan I am using a video in addition to the animation and the video itself has very similar CPU usage. Will an animated image instead of a video work better? I could have the snowfall animation in the video/gif but it's less desirable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `ImageParticle` is a good suggestion especially if you mix it with SVG. This gives QML the opportunity to compile and cache the SVG image for reuse, whereas with `ItemParticle` I think there is the burden of dynamic creation of the `Item`.

I also did a minor refactor to place the UI `Rectangle`/`Item` and Emitter at the top and the non-UI declaration `ParticleSystem` and `ItemParticle` at the bottom.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Particles

Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    
    Item {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        
        Emitter {
            id: emitter
            anchors.fill: parent
            system: particleSystem
            emitRate: 10
            lifeSpan: 4000
            sizeVariation: 5
            lifeSpanVariation: 500
            velocity: AngleDirection {
                angle: 90
                angleVariation: 10
                magnitude: 100
                magnitudeVariation: 50
            }
        }
    }
    
    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSystem
    }
        
    ImageParticle {
        system: particleSystem
        source: "Particle.qml"
    }
}

// Particle.qml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
<circle cx="4" cy="4" r="4" stroke="none" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADnXichVPJTsMwEL37K0b+gCRsEkS0EtuBWwGJu+uadFTHDva0oaD+O7Zpq7hU4IMzM+/N7mDbWUfwRE9LlAuGmVrcWUPOan9onwhHKLXyjE1Eo+CLQThTIReNs0szq+FZSRKm0QEDabV1NfCpDgQOm0RO1yOpduscjzBybp0vyHY1dMIpQ1He4z3OaL5HkrbH9sJDi0TKDcLGg6Em9YNk9l3KN9R6Fzkj+LUPRSYotfyS9IwS4z4LUjWcVBmg8U29dMLUcF5VOeTxU70Kh4LQBvziqN+QcOC/UtpKpHUNN3HK9+jCwAPzoO2fFgOhhqvqODJIcvKb0orGIC1nqbk/4KzUjLZhuTRY/ySb6aD0uK0jA9/k234M2dUuxsD7n5V5u3Qy9MN3rsV7q/k2wYaxsoQhwq79qoGPVhs/4nOiri7Lvu+L/qywrilPw2bLwOCwQtXf2o8Rr6CCS7jkY3Yt0cXaZLCec5Dr9HHp9uHPWqgRN9YoDvH9jXg/R1K8DI4x5PgbD5f9tg==)